# Is it possible to develop a chat with WCF RIA Services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

In fact, the best practice is to use duplex communications. However, I've got a test project to complete from my interviewers, and it is purposed to use RIA Services. Are there any means by which I could use RIA Services to push data to Silverlight client?

Answer (score 0):

I did it previously, 
As you say **polling** is not a good Technic. Asking to a WCF service or WCF RIA. 
For **push** I do not now. We use **pull** method for sl.

Maybe it could be possible with SignalR type js lib. By the way you would need to speak between js and SL.